# Как получить разницу между двумя датами для виджета?

Tags: java, android, дата, android-widgets

Бросил курить 11 октября 2015 года, ровно в 15 часов 20 минут, бросил сигарету и сказал себе СТОП! По этому поводу решил для себя набросать виджет, что бы каждый раз при взгляде на главный экран телефона радовал меня моим крутым достижением!

Набросал проект виджета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне вместо "Вычисляю..." вывести сколько я уже не курю в формате: Лет Дней Часов Минут ?

Что нужно вставить вот в этот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

      @Override
      public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onEnabled");
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
          int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate " + Arrays.toString(appWidgetIds));
      }

      @Override
      public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDeleted " + Arrays.toString(appWidgetIds));
      }

      @Override
      public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDisabled");
      }

}
```

СПАСИБО!

Comment: А при чём тут виджет? Вам же надо узнать только как вычислить разницу меж заданной датой и текущей датой... А это с виджетом связано...никак.

Comment: [О лирических отступлениях](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/93/177345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извиняюсь, пока что не могу прислать в нормальном виде кусок:

```
public static int getDifferenceTimeSeconds(int firstTimeHH, int firstTimeMM, int firstTimeSS, int secondTimeHH, int secondTimeMM, int secondTimeSS){ 
    int firstTime = firstTimeHH*60*60+firstTimeMM*60+firstTimeSS; 
    int secondTime = secondTimeHH*60*60+secondTimeMM*60+secondTimeSS; 
    return firstTime - secondTime; }


public static int getDifferenceDateDays(Calendar firstDate, Calendar secondDate){ 
    int firstDateDays = firstDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); 
    int secondDateDays = secondDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); 
    return firstDateDays - secondDateDays; }
```